# Accessing an attribute of a js object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node-rest-client to fetch data from an api. It all goes well until I get the data back (a js object), then I am unable to access the attributes of the response:

```
console.log("dataObject:", dataObject);
console.log("dataObject.access_token:", dataObject.access_token);
console.log("dataObject['access_token']:", dataObject['access_token']);
```

prints this to the log:

```
15:12:39 worker.1  | dataObject: {"access_token":"uzJB9nG1ZbpsJaFy","token_type":"bearer"}
15:12:39 worker.1  | dataObject.access_token: undefined
15:12:39 worker.1  | dataObject['access_token']: undefined
```

I don't understand how that is possible!

Comment: Add `console.log(typeof dataObject)`

Comment: I'm going to guess, `JSON.parse`

Comment: If it s not `JSON.parse()`, try `dataObject.get('access_token')`, I saw some API answer like that (mongoose in schemaless mode for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the data you're getting from the rest client is in string. You can quickly try the following and see if it works.

```
dataObject = JSON.parse(dataObject);
```

Had it been an object, then the line

```
console.log("dataObject.access_token:", dataObject.access_token);
```

would print

```
15:12:39 worker.1  | dataObject: [object Object]
```

However, I would suggest, find out why it is coming as string? check if you are sending `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` header properly from the API.

**Edit:**

Looks like by default `node-rest-client` expects `application/json;charset=utf-8` (No space after semicolon). Either you could send the header from API like this, or modify options in `node-rest-client` as explained [here](https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client/issues/12)

Comment: JSON is a string. That's why it's "coming as string". API would be absolutely correct in this case.

Comment: The API needs to send `content-type` header for the rest client to parse it as JSON by default

Comment: Depends on the client. `jQuery` will parse for you, but I don't think a native `XMLHttpRequest` will.

Comment: I am aware about that. But the OP asked about `node-rest-client`. Looks like you haven't used it.

Comment: I am passing these headers: headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json", "Charset":"utf-8"}

Comment: It looks a rigid rule in node-rest-client, sending `application/json;charset=utf-8` (note the space removed after semicolon) works fine with it.

Comment: the npm page states that "// parsed response body as js object", which is why I was expecting it as, well, a js object. It is indeed a string, so my immediate problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

> It all goes well until I get the data back (a js object)

That's where you went wrong. It's not a javascript object, it's a JSON string. The give away is here:

```
15:12:39 worker.1  | dataObject: {"access_token":"uzJB9nG1ZbpsJaFy","token_type":"bearer"}
```

Most (maybe all?) Javascript engines won't put `"` around property names (they are optional) when you log to console. But a JSON string, being a string, has them.

So you should be able to just do:

```
dataObject = JSON.parse(dataObject);
```

And then:

```
console.log(dataObject.access_token);
```

You don't show how you actually get the JSON in the first place, but many libraries (for example jQuery) will automatically `parse` for you.